# How to change company name in careers / jobs

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I can see most of the information for a company page is editable - except the company name.  How do you change the company name in careers?  Our company suddenly changed its name to entire lowercase letters and our HR team has asked me to update this but I cannot.

Please don't tell me the company name is a non editable primary key :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is editable, just not by users. Just send us a request to careers@stackoverflow.com to have it changed. It's a fairly manual process at the moment that is prone to breaking things if not done right.

Comment: Email sent to you guys.