# Changing company name does not update references to company across careers

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently I asked [how to change company name in careers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319030/how-to-change-company-name-in-careers-jobs).  It appears that this is some sort of admin task back at SO Headquarters.  Company name was changed but references to it across careers don't get updated.  Watermarks, drop down values still contain old company name, here's one example:

[image]

Comment: Bump - Is there any update on this?