# Edited company name in CV, but my profile still shows old company name?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I cannot seem to figure out where this needs to be changed. I don't know if it is related to this issue: [Changing company name does not update references to company across careers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319674/changing-company-name-does-not-update-references-to-company-across-careers).  I've gone into my CV and changed my company name...but when I click my profile it still shows the old company name.

Our company changed its name from ThyssenKrupp to thyssenkrupp recently, don't ask why...So I changed this company name in my traditional CV and I thought it would work, but my profile as well as my developer story shows this:

[image]

Comment: @rla4 - This isn't only for the developer story.  My main stack overflow profile has this same issue.

Comment: Noted, just wanted to ping the dev story team as well.

Comment: Are you sure it actually changed the name and not just how it is stylized in the ***logo***? There is a difference.

Comment: How long ago did you change it? You should wait to ensure it's not cached.